# Changing the location of the line continuations ('\") used in macros with clang-format

Tags: c++, clang-format

I have code that uses Macros, some of them are long.
Before running clang-format one example looks like the following:

```
    #define assertionTriggersExit { \
      std::cout.flush(); \
      std::cerr.flush(); \
      tarch::logging::Log::flushBeforeAssertion(); \
      assert(false); \
      exit(ASSERTION_EXIT_CODE); \
    }
```

After clang-format (scroll to see \ chars):

```
#define assertionTriggersExit                                                                                          \
  {                                                                                                                    \
    std::cout.flush();                                                                                                 \
    std::cerr.flush();                                                                                                 \
    tarch::logging::Log::flushBeforeAssertion();                                                                       \
    assert(false);                                                                                                     \
    exit(ASSERTION_EXIT_CODE);                                                                                         \
  }
```

The line continuations are placed at 120 characters, which is the column limit. I want clang-format to not change location of the \ characters (in general I want that they are either untouched and kept as in the original, or that they are 1-2 whitespaces away from the last character that is not ' '. I could not find the option (or the combination of options) to prevent it, could anybody help?

I am writing a fresh clang-format file based on the llvm style for a code base. The style file I have currently is as follows:

```
---
Language:        Cpp
# BasedOnStyle:  LLVM
AccessModifierOffset: -2
AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent
AlignArrayOfStructures: None
AlignConsecutiveMacros: None
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: true
AlignConsecutiveBitFields: None
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true
AlignEscapedNewlines: Right
AlignOperands:   Align
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: MultiLine
AttributeMacros:
  - __capability
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel:  false
  AfterClass:      false
  AfterControlStatement: Never
  AfterEnum:       false
  AfterFunction:   false
  AfterNamespace:  false
  AfterObjCDeclaration: false
  AfterStruct:     false
  AfterUnion:      false
  AfterExternBlock: false
  BeforeCatch:     false
  BeforeElse:      false
  BeforeLambdaBody: false
  BeforeWhile:     false
  IndentBraces:    false
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: All
BreakBeforeConceptDeclarations: true
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: false
BreakInheritanceList: AfterColon
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
BreakConstructorInitializers: AfterColon
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: false
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit:     120
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
QualifierAlignment: Left
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 2
ContinuationIndentWidth: 2
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DeriveLineEnding: true
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat:   false
EmptyLineAfterAccessModifier: Never
EmptyLineBeforeAccessModifier: LogicalBlock
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
PackConstructorInitializers: Never
BasedOnStyle:    ''
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
AllowAllConstructorInitializersOnNextLine: true
FixNamespaceComments: true
ForEachMacros:
  - foreach
  - Q_FOREACH
  - BOOST_FOREACH
IfMacros:
  - KJ_IF_MAYBE
IncludeBlocks:   Preserve
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '^"(llvm|llvm-c|clang|clang-c)/'
    Priority:        2
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   false
  - Regex:           '^(<|"(gtest|gmock|isl|json)/)'
    Priority:        3
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   false
  - Regex:           '.*'
    Priority:        1
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   false
IncludeIsMainRegex: '(Test)?$'
IncludeIsMainSourceRegex: ''
IndentAccessModifiers: false
IndentCaseLabels: false
IndentCaseBlocks: false
IndentGotoLabels: true
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentExternBlock: AfterExternBlock
IndentRequires:  false
IndentWidth:     2
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: true
#Needs clang format 15
#IndentRequiresClause: true
InsertTrailingCommas: None
JavaScriptQuotes: Leave
JavaScriptWrapImports: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: true
LambdaBodyIndentation: Signature
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: None
ObjCBinPackProtocolList: Auto
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 2
ObjCBreakBeforeNestedBlockParam: true
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: false
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 10000
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 0
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 100
PenaltyBreakOpenParenthesis: 0
PenaltyBreakString: 100
PenaltyBreakTemplateDeclaration: 100
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 10000
PenaltyIndentedWhitespace: 100
PointerAlignment: Right
PPIndentWidth:   -1
ReferenceAlignment: Pointer
ReflowComments:  false
RemoveBracesLLVM: false
SeparateDefinitionBlocks: Leave
ShortNamespaceLines: 0
SortIncludes:    CaseSensitive
SortJavaStaticImport: Before
SortUsingDeclarations: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: true
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCaseColon: false
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: false
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: false
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: false
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeParensOptions:
  AfterControlStatements: true
  AfterForeachMacros: true
  AfterFunctionDefinitionName: false
  AfterFunctionDeclarationName: false
  AfterIfMacros:   true
  AfterOverloadedOperator: false
  BeforeNonEmptyParentheses: false
SpaceAroundPointerQualifiers: Default
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceInEmptyBlock: false
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles:  Never
SpacesInConditionalStatement: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInLineCommentPrefix:
  Minimum:         1
  Maximum:         -1
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
BitFieldColonSpacing: Both
Standard:        Latest
StatementAttributeLikeMacros:
  - Q_EMIT
StatementMacros:
  - Q_UNUSED
  - QT_REQUIRE_VERSION
TabWidth:        4
UseCRLF:         false
UseTab:          Never
WhitespaceSensitiveMacros:
  - STRINGIZE
  - PP_STRINGIZE
  - BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE
  - NS_SWIFT_NAME
  - CF_SWIFT_NAME
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
AlignEscapedNewlines: DontAlign
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want that they are either untouched and kept as in the original

```
AlignEscapedNewlines: DontAlign
```

> or that they are 1-2 whitespaces away from the last character that is not ' '

```
AlignEscapedNewlines: Left
```